# Ajax request - get form data and loop through element_name[]

Tags: php, ajax

I am performing an AJAX-Reqest with form data and additional data as array (`selected_members`)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/insert.inc.php",
    data: { 
        frmData: $("#frmData").serialize(),
        selected_members: selected_members
    },
```

How can I get these data in insert.inc.php as two arrays (form data and selected_members)?
The form contains also elements with `name="element_name[]"`

```
    var_dump($_POST);
        array(2) {
  ["frmData"]=>
  string(232) "datDate=2022-02-13&tmBeginn=17%3A00&tmEnde=17%3A00&cmb_Mittel%5B%5D=1&txt_Aufwandmenge%5B%5D=1&txt_mKh%5B%5D=1&cmb_Mittel%5B%5D=2&txt_Aufwandmenge%5B%5D=2&txt_mKh%5B%5D=3&cmbGeraet=1&cmbDuese=1&txtWasser=300&cmbGasse=2&cmbAnwender=1"
  ["selected_members"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

How can I get the form data, and loop through each "row" of the three element_name[] inputs?

Comment: You can use [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert it into an associative array.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working for input elements that are named like `name[]`, see edited question

Comment: Erik, can you tell us what is the result of `echo var_dump($_POST)` at **insert.inc.php**? That would largely help us figuring out what the solution to your problem is.

Comment: Yes it does... https://3v4l.org/eas1U - You'll get those as an array, just like you would if you submitted the form normally. How else would you expect to get those? `[]` will always be converted as an indexed array (since there are no key defined). If you want those as an associate array as well, you need to define a key in the name: `name="element_name[key1]"`, `name="element_name[key2]"` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see, `cmb_item` and `txt_amount` are existing values in `$yourarray` and they are arrays of items. They do not need to be associative arrays, because they share the same `name` and differ in `value` only. In order to refer to them, you can simply do `$yourarray['cmb_item']` and `$yourarray['txt_amount']`, respectively.

EDIT

Example:

```
<?php

$foo = 'datDate=2022-02-13&tmStart=15%3A00&tmEnd=15%3A00&cmb_item%5B%5D=1&txt_amount%5B%5D=30&cmb_item%5B%5D=2&txt_amount%5B%5D=50&&cmbDevice=1';

parse_str($foo, $bar);

echo var_dump($bar['cmb_item']);
```

The result is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```